# Determining if a prefix exists in a set

Tags: ruby, algorithm, string

Given a set of strings, say:

```
"Alice"
"Bob"
"C"
"Ca"
"Car"
"Carol"
"Caroling"
"Carousel"
```

and given a single string, say:

```
"Carolers"
```

I would like a function that returns the smallest prefix not already inside the array.

For the above example, the function should return: "Caro". (A subsequent call would return "Carole")

I am very new to Ruby, and although I could probably hack out something ugly (using my C/C++/Objective-C brain), I would like to learn how to properly (elegantly?) code this up.

Comment: "The smallest substring not already inside the array" -- wouldn't that be either `C` (not a member of the array) or `rs` (doesn't occur anywhere)?

Comment: @larsmans you are correct. I've edited my post to reflect that. Oops!

Comment: Seems like you mean the smallest prefix.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution with certain performance characteristics or just something that works for a demonstration of some "canonical ruby"?  The algorithm itself seems important for this non-trivial task...

Comment: @maerics "canonical ruby" will do nicely. This is going to be used in a Rails app, but I'm not incredibly concerned about performance as much as I am learning how to not just code Ruby like it's C

Comment: Assuming you mean "longest" prefix then why wouldn't the next output sequence be "Carolin", "Carouse", "Caroler"?  If you actually mean shortest, why wouldn't the sequence be "A", "B", "Al"?  Do you instead mean something like the leftmost substring with the most matches from the existing set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a little known magical module in Ruby called [Abbrev](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/abbrev/1.9.2/frames).

```
require 'abbrev'

abbreviations = Abbrev::abbrev([
  "Alice",
  "Bob",
  "C",
  "Ca",
  "Car",
  "Carol",
  "Caroling",
  "Carousel"
])
carolers = Abbrev::abbrev(%w[Carolers])
(carolers.keys - abbreviations.keys).sort.first # => "Caro"
```

Above I took the first element but this shows what else would be available.

```
pp (carolers.keys - abbreviations.keys).sort 
# >> ["Caro", "Carole", "Caroler", "Carolers"]
```

Wrap all the above in a function, compute the resulting missing elements, and then iterate over them yielding them to a block, or use an enumerator to return them one-by-one.

This is what is generated for a single word. For an array it is more complex.

```
require 'pp'
pp Abbrev::abbrev(['cat'])
# >> {"ca"=>"cat", "c"=>"cat", "cat"=>"cat"}

pp Abbrev::abbrev(['cat', 'car', 'cattle', 'carrier'])
# >> {"cattl"=>"cattle",
# >>  "catt"=>"cattle",
# >>  "cat"=>"cat",
# >>  "carrie"=>"carrier",
# >>  "carri"=>"carrier",
# >>  "carr"=>"carrier",
# >>  "car"=>"car",
# >>  "cattle"=>"cattle",
# >>  "carrier"=>"carrier"}
```

Comment: thanks for the Abbrev gem.. it is awesome. I used my own logic to form the combination.. never knew there is a built in function :)

Comment: Periodically I'll open the ruby docs for the standard library and core just to see if anything seems like it would be useful, and Abbrev has caught my eye several times. Abbrev isn't something I need usually, but oddly enough, there's been several questions lately where it was useful. And, I keep having a nagging thought that there's something totally cool to be done with it for implementing a Ruby version of Perl's Regexp::Assemble, but so far its escaped me.

Answer (score 3):

Your question still doesn't match what you are expecting as a result. It seems that you need prefixes, not the substrings (as `"a"` would be the shortest substring not already in the array). For searching the prefix, this should suffice:

```
array = [
"Alice",
"Bob",
"C",
"Ca",
"Car",
"Carol",
"Caroling",
"Carousel",
]

str = 'Carolers'

(0..str.length).map{|i|
  str[0..i]
}.find{|s| !array.member?(s)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Ruby expert, but I think you may want to approach this problem by converting your set into a trie.  Once you have the trie constructed, your problem can be solved simply by walking down from the root of the trie, following all of the edges for the letters in the word, until you either find a node that is not marked as a word or walk off the trie.  In either case, you've found a node that isn't part of any word, and you have the shortest prefix of your word in question that doesn't already exist inside of the set.  Moreover, this would let you run any number of prefix checks quickly, since after you've built up the trie the algorithm takes time at most linear in the length of the string.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're asking for other than an example of some Ruby code to find common prefixes.  I'll assume you want to find the smallest string which is a prefix of the most number of strings in the given set.  Here's an example implementation:

```
class PrefixFinder
  def initialize(words)
    @words = Hash[*words.map{|x|[x,x]}.flatten]
  end
  def next_prefix
    max=0; biggest=nil
    @words.keys.sort.each do |word|
      0.upto(word.size-1) do |len|
        substr=word[0..len]; regex=Regexp.new("^" + substr)
        next if @words[substr]
        count = @words.keys.find_all {|x| x=~regex}.size
        max, biggest = [count, substr] if count > max
        #puts "OK: s=#{substr}, biggest=#{biggest.inspect}"
      end
    end
    @words[biggest] = biggest if biggest
    biggest
  end
end

pf = PrefixFinder.new(%w(C Ca Car Carol Caroled Carolers))
pf.next_prefix # => "Caro"
pf.next_prefix # => "Carole"
pf.next_prefix # => "Caroler"
pf.next_prefix # => nil
```

No comment on the performance (or correctness) of this code but it does show some Ruby idioms (instance variables, iteration, hashing, etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
  => inn = ["Alice","Bob","C","Ca","Car","Carol","Caroling","Carousel"]
  => y = Array.new
  => str="Carolers"
```

Split the given string to an array

```
  => x=str.split('')
  # ["C","a","r","o","l","e","r","s"]
```

Form all the combination

```
  => x.each_index {|i| y << x.take(i+1)}
  # [["c"], ["c", "a"], ["c", "a", "r"], ["c", "a", "r", "o"], ["c", "a", "r", "o", "l"], ["c", "a", "r", "o", "l", "e"], ["c", "a", "r", "o", "l", "e", "r"], ["c", "a", "r", "o", "l", "e", "r", "s"]]
```

Using Join to concatenate the

```
  => y =  y.map {|s| s.join }
  # ["c", "ca", "car", "caro", "carol", "carole", "caroler", "carolers"]
```

Select the first item from the y thats not available in the input Array

```
  => y.select {|item| !inn.include? item}.first
```

You will get **"caro"**

Putting together all

```
 def FindFirstMissingItem(srcArray,strtocheck)
   y=Array.new
   x=strtocheck.split('')
   x.each_index {|i| y << x.take(i+1)}
   y=y.map {|s| s.join}
   y.select {|item| !srcArray.include? item}.first
 end
```

And call

```
 => inn = ["Alice","Bob","C","Ca","Car","Carol","Caroling","Carousel"]
 => str="Carolers"

 FindFirstMissingItem inn,str
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple version (but not very Rubyish):

```
str = 'Carolers'
ar = %w(Alice Bob C Ca Car Carol Caroling Carousel)

substr = str[0, n=1]
substr = str[0, n+=1] while ar.include? substr
puts substr
```